# How would I write a virtual CD/DVD burner that would allow programs that burn to write to ISO?

Tags: iso, dvd-burning, cd-burning

I want to write an app that will allow a program like iTunes which normally will recognize a DVD/CD burner to recognize a virtual one and then write to it creating an ISO. I would guess to use C/C++... can someone point me in the right direction as to how this can be done?

Basically it would be a virtual CD/DVD burner that would output an ISO file to the hard drive. I want to do this for both the usefulness of it as well as the challenge, just need an idea of how to approach it, have no idea how to write virtual hardware.

Comment: I think you would need to look up creating drivers for your own 'hardware' that some one can install onto their computer. Your drivers will then do things like report that there is a blank disc in the drive. You may need to have a simple configuration program that can set things like what type of disc will appear to be in the drive. You will also need to look up how to handle the ISO file format and so forth. It may be easier and wiser to look into an exciting open source ISO mounting software and mod that to allow for burning.I'm sure tools already exist though for straight creating an ISO

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VMWare has a [developer kit](http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vddk/) for virtual drives. That might be a good place to start.

Comment: Can you suggest same for JAVA ..?